# Tip120 simulation shows explosion

Tags: transfer-function

I am trying to use TIP120 for my inverted switch where I wish to have my DC water pump(rated at 5v, 3W, 600mA) running when switch is open (in actual these will probes that will complete path when there is ample water in between them) and when switch is closed the transistor should shut off.

I have calculated the (base current - Ib) for the above load at 0.6mA (600mA/1000) and base resistor Rb at 4.1 kohms.

I am using circuit wizard for simulation, which is showing explosion on the transistor when the state of switch is changed. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the below mentioned circuit

[image]

I tried this sample circuit at

https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/1/9/3/switch-animated-600h.gif

but had similar prediction of transistor exploding. Can I get some information on why the simulation is predicting exploded transistor. I have also tried placing diode after the Emitter but no luck in simulation

thanks
Imran

Comment: Does the motor current exceed the transistor rating?

Comment: You need a flyback diode across the inductive load. I don't know if your simulation is picking that up- you should provide simulated base current and collector current values or we are just guessing. A Darlington is *really* not a great way to switch 5V since it will leave you with only about 3V for the motor.  A logic-level MOSFET is preferably.

Comment: @SolarMike which part of rating that might be? The motor here is rated at 4.5V only. Well I tried 2N2222A and 2N3904 but had similar result

Comment: @SpehroPefhany well that seems right because VCE is 2V..so that leaves 3V but still does not explain the explosion

Comment: Did you try the flyback diode? When the transistor turns off (not on) the voltage will likely spike up to cause the transistor to break down, at least in your simulation. Depends on how far from reality your motor model is. If it's just a resistor that won't happen in simulation. If it's a pure inductor + series resistor it will happen. Neither represents a motor load very  well. A stalled motor will draw considerably in excess of its running current. I hope you recognize that you have provided woefully inadequate information.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I did provide the motor ratings.. 5V, 3W, 600mA. I am applying 0.6 mA base current and base resistor is at 4.1k to drop volts down to 2.5V as VBE is 2.5 according to datasheet. What else am I missing? I will apply the flyback diode and post back..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a flyback diode (a diode across the load).

When the transistor turns off (not on) the (collector) voltage will likely spike up to cause the transistor to break down, at least in your simulation. This is because the motor has some inductance. Inductance opposes a rapid change in current, by changing the voltage, so when the transistor starts to turn off the voltage at the collector rises to maintain the current until something stops it (in reality it might be transistor breakdown, or ringing from capacitance).

Depends on how far from reality your motor **model** is. If it's just a resistor that won't happen in simulation. If it's a pure inductor + series resistor it will happen. Neither simplified model represents a motor load very well.

A stalled motor will draw considerably in excess of its running current, because of back-EMF, for example.

Answer (score -1):

well this made the explosion go away

[image]

Comment: Could you explain _why_ it makes the explosion go away?

Comment: I will repeat the same information that is in my comment in an answer.